# Responsive Menu in WordPress Storefront Theme Does Not Collapse

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I have an issue that just started today after I updated WooCommerce to the latest version 4.1.1, but the issue doesn't seem to be related to this update. The responsive menu for the middle screen size (tablet mode?: 768 - 1060 pixels width) does not collapse, but works fine for the smallest screen size (mobile/handheld mode?: 767 and below pixels width). When the issue occurs, after resizing the window, the menu starts off expanded and does not collapse when clicking the menu button, but the menu goes back to normal when resizing the browser further down to 767 pixels. Here is [the website](https://staging.mariesguiltfreebakery.ca). I also enabled Jetpack and added the Stripe Payment method today, but can't think of anything else that could of caused this. I am not using any WordPress cache management plugins. I am using a custom `storefront-child` theme I created with additional css and some changes in php, but the issue still occurs with the default storefront theme with no changes. Everything is working great so far except this one issue.

I have done the following so far:

1. Downgraded WooCommerce from 4.1.1 to 4.1.0 using the following steps:

   a) Deactivate WooCommerce plugin (don’t delete the Woo-Commerce plugin in the administration panel).
   b) Download WooCommerce version that you want to downgrade (plugin url).
   c) Login to your hosting through FTP or Hosting Panel.
   d) Browse to wp-content/plugins.
   e) You will see woocommerce directory.
   f) Replace the existing woocommerce directory with that newly extracted.
   g) Activate WooCommerce plugin.
2. Deactivated the Storefront theme and replaced it with a fresh downloaded copy in the `wp-content\themes` folder by first renaming the original storefront theme folder.
3. Switched from the custom child theme to the default replaced storefront theme.
4. Deactivated all plugins.
5. Tested in Chrome (Incognito Window) after each change.

However, the issue still persists, but the issue disappears when switching to another theme like [Classy Lite](https://wordpress.org/themes/classy-lite). Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this or where to look? I'm also attaching a screen shot of what the responsive menu looks like when it's working and when it's not working:

- [Responsive Menu Not Working (768 - 1060 pixels)](https://ibb.co/DCszsfJ)
- [Responsive Menu Working (767 pixels and below)](https://ibb.co/PtRm1rZ)

**UPDATE-EDIT-1:**

For reference, here is the CSS used by Storefront to create the three screen sizes:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    /* ===== FULL SIZE SCREEN ===== */
}
@media (max-width: 66.4989378333em) {
    /* ===== TABLET SCREEN ===== */
}
@media (max-width: 568px) {
    /* ===== MOBILE SCREEN ===== */
}
```

**UPDATE-EDIT-2:**

Ok, so I see now the reason why the menu button isn't working on the second screen size (max-width: 66.4989378333em) is because the navigation menu functionality isn't actually there behind the CSS, which I can see when applying the default storefront theme (no menu button appears). So I'm guessing there is a PHP file I need to find and play with to try and get the responsive menu button back for `@media (max-width: 66.4989378333em)`. Perhaps something changed that caused the WordPress database to hold an old value from the storefront theme and it may reset if I find out how to toggle the change in PHP?

UPDATE-EDIT-3:

I now know where the issue is. It's where the two media queries overlap, which is between 768px - 1063px (66.4989378333em), so turns out it is CSS related.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what caused this issue, It seems it might be a theme update that happened.  But I think I found a fix.  Add this to your theme's custom CSS.

```
@media (min-width: 1063px)
.primary-navigation {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that doesn't solve the issue on my end when adding this code to my additional css. I suspected it might have something do with the the `display` style, but I only found one reference to it in my additional css, which doesn't change anything when removing it.

Comment: Are you able to update your theme? or even revert to an older version of that theme?

Comment: Thanks, I just tested this by downgrading the storefront theme from version 2.5.6 to [version 2.5.5](https://github.com/woocommerce/storefront/releases/tag/version%2F2.5.5), but still the same issue. With the default storefront theme applied the issue persists as you can see with the menu button not appearing until resizing the browser window below 768 pixels.

Comment: Oh, did you want your menu collapsed at all screen sizes? even full width?  Because your older version of storefront is working as expected right now.  I just looked.

Comment: No I only want the menu collapsed at the first two screen sizes and not at full width, which is the default. Originally the responsive menu button appears when resizing the screen below 1061 pixels (what chrome tells me the size is) or more precisely 66.4989378333em (the exact value used by the default storefront theme css). So there are by default three screen sizes used by storefront where the menu button appears when resizing below 66.4989378333em or 1061 pixels and again when resizing below 768 pixels, but with my website the menu button only appears when going below 768 pixels.

Comment: I'm not sure there are 3?  I actually have an old test website that I made a year or so ago and I actually used the storefront theme, and haven't updated woocommerce or storefront on this site and its behaving exactly like yours is now when you reverted to the older storefront theme. check it out here: http://marketplace.tradingcardmint.com/

Comment: I just checked your site and yes I see your site is behaving like mine is now. However, while in Chrome developer mode inspecting the code I see two media screen sizes on my website and only one on yours when resizing the window. Here are the three screen sizes used by storefront in my website (the current default):

- [min-width: 768px](https://ibb.co/DMkWcRk)
- [max-width: 66.4989378333em](https://ibb.co/TPB0XF2)
- [max-width: 568px](https://ibb.co/fFZpfNH)

Comment: Ahh you are correct, mine has all 3 too.  I really think the menu problem is happening because of the new storefront theme update.  Are you able to live with the old version of storefront? otherwise maybe wait till a new storefront update comes out.  That's my best guess.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt, I see you are using storefront version 2.4.3 (released Feb 5, 2019), where I have been using version 2.5.6 (released May 4, 2020) and now 2.5.5 (released Feb 27, 2020). Both versions I tested have the same affect, and I actually was using version 2.5.6 shortly after it was released, but my issue only started today. So I don't see how this is version related. Perhaps if nobody else has any ideas, I'll have to make a local copy of the site and see if I can replicate it there.

Comment: Yeah no problem, I'm out of ideas for what might be causing it.  Possible some of that custom CSS you said you added before.  I wish you the best of luck in figuring it out though.

Comment: Thanks, yes I suspected most people would point at the custom CSS as the culprit, but that is only applied on the child theme and is completely removed when switching to the default storefront theme. I also added a comment to my original post explaining how I'm not using any WordPress cache management plugins, and I'm testing in Chrome incognito mode as well as Safari, and still can't pinpoint where the issue is.